# Why can't I suggest this edit?

Tags: bug, edits

I just saw [a post which is/was missing a new-line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50504244/9627166), causing code to be displayed as part of the first paragraph:

> When I press login button the window is not responding. Can anyone help me with this?
>      import Tkinter as tk
>      from Tkinter import *
>      from functools import partial
>      from pylab import plot, show, xlabel, ylabel
>      from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
>      from matplotlib.figure import Figure
>
> ```
> from bankaccount import BankAccount
>
> win = tk.Tk()
> # Set window size here to '440x640' pixels
> win.geometry("440x640")
> # Set window title here to 'FedUni Banking'
> win.title("FedUni Banking")
> ```
>
> ...

Should be:

> When I press login button the window is not responding. Can anyone help me with this?
>
> ```
> import Tkinter as tk
> from Tkinter import *
> from functools import partial
> from pylab import plot, show, xlabel, ylabel
> from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
> from matplotlib.figure import Figure
>
> from bankaccount import BankAccount
>
> win = tk.Tk()
> # Set window size here to '440x640' pixels
> win.geometry("440x640")
> # Set window title here to 'FedUni Banking'
> win.title("FedUni Banking")
> ```
>
> ...

I tried to edit this post by adding another return character, but when I tryed to submit the edit, it just came up with:

> - It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
> - Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

I then tried to fix some grammar and add the [`tkinter`] tag, but I still couldn't submit the edit.

The code displaying as part of the first paragraph is clearly an issue for this post and I don't see why my edit was blocked. Could the algorithm be fixed, so that formatting edits count as "substantial"? If not, why?

Comment: Dosn't it look like that post is mostly code to you?

Comment: What I meant is that the error messages that you received (and shown us here in your question) when trying to submit that edit should explain why you can't submit that edit. Don't they? Why not?

Comment: @yivi No. Look at how the code is displayed as part of the first paragraph without any returns. It made the code **very** hard to read.

Comment: No? But I do feel the error messages are clear enough. First message: _the post would be mostly code, so it wouldn't be a good post_. Second message might require some additional explaining: _since your edits still need to be peer reviewed, they need to be substantial enough as to not occupy valuable reviewers time with trivial edits_. If an edit is less than 6 characters long, leave it to a higher reputation user who will be able to edit it directly, without going the review queue. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @yivi So people with enough reputation to skip the review queue aren't affected by this? Ok. It's clearer now, but I still don't see why a big formatting change isn't considered substantial.

Comment: The first error would affect users no matter their reputation. A post that's mostly code wouln't be acceptable anyway.

Comment: The OP already fixed it by himself, the machine did not stop him.  I'll have to add yet another bullet to the list of things that no-rep users can do that nobody else can do.  Sigh.

Comment: @HansPassant The OP fixed it *by adding the explanation to the question that was missing*, not by just making a minor formatting change like this user was trying to do while leaving the question as almost entirely code.  Their error didn't trigger either error message *because they made a far more significant edit that actually addressed both problems*.  That's the system working as designed.